# deploying angulardart image on docker

Tags: angular, docker, dart

hi im trying to deploy an angulardart 9https://angulardart.xyz/0 application on docker but whenever i run the container. the link doesnt work .

this is the docker file

FROM google/dart:2.10.5

COPY /angulardart/pubspec.yaml /app/

WORKDIR /app/

RUN dart pub get

ADD pubspec.* /app/

RUN dart pub global activate webdev

RUN export PATH="$PATH:/root/.pub-cache/bin"

ADD . /app/

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["webdev", "serve"]

Comment: probably because your app binds localhost. You should bind 0.0.0.0.

Comment: i tried it it didnt work . also the docker file i have written it by my self because theres no documentation can you check it